# Angular Universal - Transfer state is empty if url have unsafe character - duplicate xhr calls

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, server-side-rendering, universal, angular-transfer-state

I'm using Angualar(12) with Angular Universal. I ran into a problem with a transfer state between server and client side. I'm using **TransferHttpCacheModule** in client side, and **ServerTransferStateModule** in server side module. I don't have any custom transfer state implementation.

For example:

Test URL: **/a/b/c**

This url doesn't contain any unsafe characters and everything works fine. HTML response has expected body and **serverApp-state** has expected data.

Test url: **/a/b/여**

This url have unsafe character and browser request for HTML looks like **/a/b/%EC%97%AC**. HTML respose for that request doesn't have expected body, and
`<script id="serverApp-state" type="application/json">{}</script></body></html>` is empty and client side duplicates xhr calls.

Any ideas how to prevent duplicate xhr calls in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I used `encodeURIComponent` in utf-16 url parts.